# Q#: dynamically assigning (or updating) multidimensional Qubit arrays

Tags: programming, q#

**Question: how to dynamically assign qubits to variables?**

e.g., say I want to represent a matrix of qubits:

$matrix := \{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, ..., \vec{v_r}\}$

where each vector consists of $dim$ many coefficients of each $bitlength$ many qubits.

(To the best of my knowledge) Q# only allows to initiate one-dimensional Qubit arrays:

```
using ( allQubits = Qubit[rank * dim * bitlength] ) {
    // Some Code
}
```

Which leaves us with the task to assign a partition of that qubit array to variables.

I see three ways of doing that, that first seems very messy, the other two I did not get to work:

1. Remembering indices in the qubit array (this will be messy)
2. Getting a representation of a three dimensional qubits array: $Qubit[rank][dim][bitlength]$
3. Getting a custom type of QubitVectors and getting an array of those.

*Any solution is welcome, does not have to follow any of these approaches.*

---

Lets start with a $Qubit[rank][dim][bitl]$ array. Using the [Partitioned](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arrays.partitioned?view=qsharp-preview) function, one can split the *allQubits* array into smaller parts, e.g., the qubits that represent a single vector.

```
// Splits a given qubit array into chunks of length size
operation splitQubitArray( allQubits : Qubit[], chunkSize : Int ) : Qubit[][]
{   
    Fact(Length(allQubits) % chunkSize == 0, "Qubit array can not be splitted into equally sized chunks");
    Fact(Length(allQubits) / chunkSize > 0, "Qubit array length is smaller than chunk size.");
    let numChunks = Length(allQubits) / chunkSize;
    mutable arraySplit = new Int[numChunks];
    for (i in 0..(numChunks - 1))
    {
        set arraySplit w/= i <- chunkSize;
    }
    let res = Partitioned(arraySplit, allQubits);
    Fact(Length(res[numChunks]) == 0, "Qubit array not split equally.");
    return res;
}

// Split AllQubits into rank many parts.
// Each part contains dim * bitl many qubits.
mutable allVecQubits = splitQubitArray( allQubits, dim * bitl );
```

Now we have a two dimensional array, where each entry of the first dimension represents a vector. One can split these further to get out a single vector variable, but I could not figure out how to put this into a iterable array...

```
mutable vec_1 = splitQubitArray(allVecQubits[0], rank);
mutable vec_2 = splitQubitArray(allVecQubits[1], rank);
...
```

---

Option 3, the [type model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/type-model?view=qsharp-preview): we define a type that contains a vector.

```
newtype customVec = (Data : Qubit[][]);
```

This leaves me with the problem that I am not able to initialize an array of that type...

```
mutable qbVectorArray = customVec[0]; // this does not work
mutable qbVectorArray = new customVec[0]; // this does not work
mutable qbVectorArray = customVec(new Qubit[][]); // this does not work
```

---

As a note on the side: 
I tried to consule the documentation in [copy-and-update expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/expressions?view=qsharp-preview#copy-and-update-expressions) but could not figure out how to do this, if the custom type contains Qubits. Furthermore the webpage containing the "update-and-reassign statements" for Q# Arrays which is linked in the [type model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/type-model?view=qsharp-preview) page seems to be unavailable.
An example or guide on how to deal with custom types with Qubits would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important thing to note is that arrays of `Qubit` aren't special in Q#, such that a solution that allows for splitting an array of type `'T[]` into `'T[][][]` will also work for arrays of qubits such as what you get from a `using` statement.

From that perspective, your solution is almost there already; you just need to generalize `splitQubitArray` into a function that takes `'T` instead, then you can call that with `'T` being `Qubit[]` instead of `Qubit`.
Turning your operation into a function and adding a type parameter, we get the following:

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;

function Chunked<'T>(array : 'T[], chunkSize : Int) : 'T[][] {
    Fact(Length(array) % chunkSize == 0, "Array can not be splitted into equally sized chunks");
    Fact(Length(array) / chunkSize > 0, "Array length is smaller than chunk size.");
    let numChunks = Length(array) / chunkSize;
    let res = Partitioned(ConstantArray(numChunks, chunkSize), array);
    Fact(Length(res[numChunks]) == 0, "Qubit array not split equally.");
    // Note that since Parititoned always returns
    // one more array than the length of the array
    // of chunk sizes, chop off the last element of its result.
    return Most(res);
}
```

This can then be used twice to turn an array of type `'T[]` into an array of type `'T[][][]` *for any* element type `'T[]`. For example, we can chunk an array of type `Int[]` into a rank-three array of integers:

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Arrays;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;

function Example() : Unit {
    let rank3 = Chunked(Chunked(RangeAsIntArray(1.. 5 * 2 * 3), 2), 3);
    Message($"Rank-3 array: {rank3}");
    Message($"Length(rank3) = {Length(rank3)}");
    Message($"Length(rank3[0]) = {Length(rank3[0])}");
    Message($"Length(rank3[0][0]) = {Length(rank3[0][0])}");
}
```

This gives us as our output:

```
Rank-3 array: [[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],[[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]],[[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]],[[19,20],[21,22],[23,24]],[[25,26],[27,28],[29,30]]]
Length(rank3) = 5
Length(rank3[0]) = 3
Length(rank3[0][0]) = 2
```

In your example above, then, you could use this new function to make a rank-3 array of qubits:

```
let qubitsAsRank3Array = Chunked(Chunked(allVecQubits), dim), bitlength);
let vec1 = qubitsAsRank3Array[0];
let vec1 = qubitsAsRank3Array[1];
// ...
```

---

This example can be run online at: https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/cgranade/e4a837dcb37a4e60f8e971cf1372a2ef/master